# Download chunked resource with wget?

Tags: asp.net, curl, wget, chunked-encoding

There's a sample ASP.NET project with this controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Response.Write("test1234");
       Response.Clear();
       Response.Flush();
       Response.Write("test5");
       Response.End();
   }
}
```

In the browser (Chrome 10) I see "test5" and 
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked

When trying to download with wget (from the most recent Cygwin) I get

```
$ wget -S  --read-timeout=60 http://127.0.0.1/EmptyWebSite/test/
--2011-04-05 23:25:51--  http://127.0.0.1/EmptyWebSite/test/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
  Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2011 20:25:51 GMT
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Type: text/html
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

[ <=>  ] 0           --.-K/s   in 0s
```

And the file is (obviously) empty

What's going wrong? Can I download such a resource with wget / curl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with WGET. From [bugs.debian.org](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=407526)

> Wget has zero support for chunked transfer encodings (and therefore, for
>   HTTP/1.1). It will only ever send HTTP/1.0 requests, which means that a
>   HTTP/1.1 response is illegal (as is the chunked encoding).

Curl supports HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 5):

Wget has a support of HTTP/1.1 and chunked transfer since version 1.13

Answer (score 0):

Ah, solved with 
    curl -v URL...